# Prevent suspend no matter what?

Tags: release-freya, macintosh, power, suspend

I'm running Freya on a MacBook Pro 2013 edition.

Suspend doesn't ever work as planned. It takes quite a while to actually get to sleep and it'll often wake itself back up again, and when it does, it seems to have taken out the entire networking stack and neither my USB 3 Ethernet adapter nor my wireless USB dongle work any more.

The main problem is that it always suspends when the lid is closed, which I want to never happen.

Is there a way to fully prevent it from *ever* suspending? I'm using it with 2 DisplayPort monitors right now, but I can't close the lid for fear that it'll suspend itself and screw everything up.

Answer (score 1):

You could install Caffeine from `ppa:caffeine-developers/ppa`.

It runs as an indicator and can be used to prevent suspension.

You can also try this method, [taken](https://askubuntu.com/a/568440/1992) from [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com):

> For me it is important to just disable the "automatic Suspend" Because
>   I still want to be able to do the "manual Suspend" in
>   `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.disable-suspend.pkla`
>
> So, I used:
>
> ```
> [Disable suspend (upower)]
> Identity=unix-user:*
> Action=org.freedesktop.upower.suspend
> ResultActive=no
> ResultInactive=no
> ResultAny=no
>
> [Disable suspend (logind)]
> Identity=unix-user:*
> Action=org.freedesktop.login1.suspend
> ResultActive=yes
> ResultInactive=no
> ResultAny=yes
>
> [Disable suspend when others are logged in (logind)]
> Identity=unix-user:*
> Action=org.freedesktop.login1.suspend-multiple-sessions
> ResultActive=yes
> ResultInactive=no
> ResultAny=yes
> ```
>
> Now I can click "Suspend" in the logoff menu. But the PC keeps running
>   unless I send it to "Suspend".

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I don't have that file on my computer. Nothing exists in `50-local.d`. I'll look elsewhere.

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay use `locate` from the command line to find the file.

Comment: I did. There's nothing with a similar name.

Comment: You may have to create the file.

Comment: Noted. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

I use elementary OS freya and there is a GUI app for powermanagement. Remove all instances of sleep, suspend and hibernate. You can leave turn the display off.

That disables automatical suspend, but  will leave the manual suspend up in the menu in the right upper corner.
Mbr Patte